# Validate email attribute only if it's present

Tags: php, laravel, validation, email-validation

I want email validation rule to fail only when email attribute is present. From what I can tell, email validation is performed unconditionally in Laravel.

To give you a bigger picture, the site I'm writing allows to log in with email/password, or with social networks (socialite). And not every network reveals user email. And I'm in the process of moving validation rules to models (`watson/validating` package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it can be found [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules), you can use the `sometimes` rule which validates the corresponding field only when it is present:

```
$rules = [
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email|otherValidationsHere',
];
```